# Как дублировать несколько элементов из html формы?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть форма в html. В ней множество input и output. Мне нужно их продублировать и отобразить ниже. Также мне надо всё это обрабатывать в pythom(flask) и следовательно нужно автоматически менять id, чтобы всё не слетело. Пробовал через js, но пока что не выходит.

Вот кнопка, по клику которой отправляется запрос на сервер
$('#addServId').click(addServ)

Вот функция, которая её обрабатывает.

```
function addServ(){
$('.client').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
$('.serv').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
$('.core').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
$('.ram').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
$('.sata').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
$('.sas').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
$('.ssd').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
$('.res').clone().appendTo($('#virtualId'))
```

}

P.S. virtualId - это id формы.

Буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: кода в вопросе нет. что слетело?

Comment: Если id не поменять, то при обработке следующего запроса программа будет считывать разную информацию с 2-х одинаковых id. Я старался максимально подробно объяснить

Comment: 1) код вставьте; 2) и что мешает поменять ид-ы?

Comment: 1) Добавил код. 2) Ничего, просто я не знаю как это сделать)

Comment: Форм несколько. Сейчас немного переделал. Вместо #virtualId прописал div в самой форме и обращаюсь теперь так: $('.virtual'). Всё хорошо работает, но я так и не нашёл как клонировать и параллельно менять id

Comment: или проблема в том, что в 2-х инпутах должно автоматически оставаться одно и то же значение?

Comment: Под разными формами я имел ввиду то, что на сайте она не одна. Но клонирую я элементы в одну форму.

Comment: Вы клонируете элементы, добавляя _бизнес-сущность_, или клонируете элементы, чтобы показать ту же бизнес-сущность в другом месте?

Comment: Добавляя бизнес-сущность

Comment: (я ранее не то написал)... id уникален для документа, а name для формы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
const res = $('.res').clone()
res.attr('id',newResId)
res.appendTo($('#virtualId'))
```

Comment: Если форма просто субмитится, то менять надо не 'id', a 'name'